# PHP CLI getting input from user and then dumping into variable possible?

Tags: php

Is it possible to get input from a user using PHP CLI, then dump the input into a variable and then the script goes ahead. Just like the C++ `cin` function.

Is that possible and, if yes, then how?

Maybe not only PHP but maybe with some Linux commands?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Have a look at this PHP manual page
http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php

in particular

```
<?php
echo "Are you sure you want to do this?  Type 'yes' to continue: ";
$handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
$line = fgets($handle);
if(trim($line) != 'yes'){
    echo "ABORTING!\n";
    exit;
}
echo "\n";
echo "Thank you, continuing...\n";
?>
```

Comment: Works but any better approach ?

Comment: as ofc reading that file will make the program some whatslower

Comment: Well PHP was designed for the Web, I would imagine their support for command line stuff is a patch at the best. Something like Python is a better fit for writing command line stuff.

Comment: and if i want multiple inputs then how do i do that with this ?

Comment: i have to repeat it over and over again

Comment: @kritya - My only advice if you choose this approach would be to use the `STDIN` constant instead of "php://stdin" as recommended in [the PHP wrappers documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php).

Comment: Write a function that gets input and reuse your function.

Answer (score 101):

To read a line from standard input in php CLI mode, you can do:

```
$fin = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
$line = fgets($fin);
```

On older versions of PHP `STDIN` constant may also work

```
$line = fgets(STDIN);
```

---

To read all the content from input use:

```
file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Comment: Simply append another line like this: `$line2 = fgets(STDIN);`

Comment: And if you want to read in a loop until EOF then use `while (FALSE !== ($line = fgets(STDIN))) {
   echo "line=$line";
}`

Comment: `STDIN` is not always defined so the accepted answer is better.

Comment: In source code of CORE php > 5.3.6 it is defined as:

```define('STDIN', fopen('php://stdin', 'r'));

define('STDOUT', fopen('php://stdout', 'w'));

define('STDERR', fopen('php://stderr', 'w'));```

Comment: I realize this is a very old answer but `STDIN` is not defined in any modern environment I've used.

Comment: @EatenbyaGrue: Thanks for your comment. I haven't visited this answer in all these years. I have edited it to make it work with newer php versions.

Answer (score 9):

In this example I'm extending Devjar's example. Credits for him for example code. Last code example is simplest and safest in my opinion.

When you use his code:

```
<?php
echo "Are you sure you want to do this?  Type 'yes' to continue: ";
$handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
$line = fgets($handle);
if(trim($line) != 'yes'){
echo "ABORTING!\n";
exit;
}
echo "\n";
echo "Thank you, continuing...\n";
?>
```

You should note stdin mode **is not** binary-safe. You should add "b" to your mode and use following code:

```
<?php
echo "Are you sure you want to do this?  Type 'yes' to continue: ";
$handle = fopen ("php://stdin","rb"); // <-- Add "b" Here for Binary-Safe
$line = fgets($handle);
if(trim($line) != 'yes'){
echo "ABORTING!\n";
exit;
}
echo "\n";
echo "Thank you, continuing...\n";
?>
```

Also you can set max charters. This is my personal example. I'll suggest to use this as your code. It's also recommended to use directly STDIN than "php://stdin".

```
<?php
/* Define STDIN in case if it is not already defined by PHP for some reason */
if(!defined("STDIN")) {
define("STDIN", fopen('php://stdin','rb'))
}

echo "Hello! What is your name (enter below):\n";
$strName = fread(STDIN, 80); // Read up to 80 characters or a newline
echo 'Hello ' , $strName , "\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

similarly you could create a function, like python.

```
$line = input("Please put in a number: ");
if ($line === 20){
    echo true;
} else {
    echo false;
}

function input(string $prompt = null): string
{
    echo $prompt;
    $handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
    $output = fgets ($handle);
    return trim ($output);
}
```