# PHP-CLI How to write in user input?

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I want to get predefined user input.

```
echo 'Enter value: ';
# here write some 'default value'
$value = fgets(STDIN);
```

So then user get prompt, he can edit input.

```
Enter value: default value # Here we can backslash and write new one.
```

How to achieve?

Comment: @RoyalBg, php-cli tag does not set for some reason.

Comment: You can use the $argv array for parameters. Also, check prompting for input here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543841/php-cli-getting-input-from-user-and-then-dumping-into-variable-possible . Yeah, I saw it later, it was not tagged, but only in the title :)

Comment: It should be interactive.

Comment: as stated in the marked answer, you can use `if ($value != 'predefined_answer') { // doSmth()` or if it's null, assign value, different than fgets()

Comment: May be it can be achieved with expect://?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not the default/commen way of handling this stuff in shell scripts. In almost any programm you'll find something like this:

```
Enter your value: [Default Value]

$default = "Default Value";
echo "Enter your value: [", $default, "]";
$result = fgets(STDIN);
if (empty($result)) $result = $default;
```

Where as the default value gets set when the STDIN of that get was empty.

I'm pretty surr that the thing you want to achive isn't possible at all.

Comment: I think that too. And for now I use same approach. I need to be sure.