# How to redirect echo command output to a text file in PHP

Tags: php

I want to redirect echo command output to a text file.My PHP code contain echo $TOKEN;Here $TOKEN contains variable value i want to write this value into a text file. Any one can help on this.

Thanks in adavance.

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Yes i tried so many times.Script will executing but input parameter not taking. I tried like this ./projectlist.sh $TOKEN.Here $TOKEN is the input argument for the script.

Comment: Related to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543841/php-cli-getting-input-from-user-and-then-dumping-into-variable-possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `fopen/fwrite` to write to a file (this will create the output.txt if it does not exist, else overwrites it)

```
$myfile = fopen("output.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $TOKEN);
fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: wooow This is work for me.Thanks  you so much.Here output.txt not over writing every time append the content .Is it any option to overwrite.

Comment: @abhi [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), just read the documentation.

Comment: fbo3264,Yes now it is working fine.Thanks for spending your valuable time.

Comment: You're welcome! If you like you can update my answer :)

Answer (score 4):

try standard bash notation:

```
php script.php > file.txt
```

Comment: This won't work on a website. I think a solution is needed to write echo command output to a text file from within a php file.

Answer (score 1):

or easily with pure php:

```
//rewrite
file_put_contents("myfile.txt","string to file");

//add
file_put_contents("myfile.txt","string to file", FILE_APPEND);
```